# How to change responsive breakpoint values in MUI theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, breakpoints

I'm using the v1 beta of MUI. The media query breakpoints are not the same as Bootstrap v4 breakpoints I'm using and I wanted to override the values of the MUI breakpoints to match that of Bootstraps.

I need to do something like below but I'm not finding enough documentation to get it to work.

**Current error is:**

> "Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" when trying to
> reference createBreakpoints() as a function.

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme, createBreakpoints } from "material-ui/styles";
    
const breakpointValues = {
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576,
  md: 768,
  lg: 992,
  xl: 1200,
};

const breakpoints = createBreakpoints({ values: breakpointValues });
const theme = createMuiTheme({ breakpoints });
```

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <App />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 15):

Oh, I figured out out. Needed to pass my new values to the createMuiTheme func which internally calls createBreakpoints func.

```
const breakpointValues = {
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576,
  md: 768,
  lg: 992,
  xl: 1200,
};
const theme = createMuiTheme({ breakpoints: { values: breakpointValues } });
```

Answer (score 2):

**MUI v5 Update**

Before you create custom breakpoints, have a look at the default breakpoint values [here](https://mui.com/customization/breakpoints/#default-breakpoints) first to see if they suit your need. If you still decide to create your own values:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      mobile: 0,
      tablet: 640,
      laptop: 1024,
      desktop: 1200,
    },
  },
});
```

The code above will discard all breakpoint values from the default theme. If you wish to include the original values, create a `defaultTheme` and merge those values like this:

```
const defaultTheme = createTheme();
const theme = createTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      ...defaultTheme.breakpoints.values,
      mobile: 0,
      tablet: 640,
      laptop: 1024,
      desktop: 1200,
    },
  },
});
```

For Typescript users, you also need to update your custom breakpoint names:

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface BreakpointOverrides {
    mobile: true; // adds the `mobile` breakpoint
    tablet: true;
    laptop: true;
    desktop: true;
  }
}
```

### Usage

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Content />
</ThemeProvider>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Reference

- https://mui.com/customization/breakpoints/#custom-breakpoints